# how keep screen in landscape mode after locking and unlocking the device?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I made a game with Adobe AIR and ActionScript 3 for Android devices.

My problem is with landscape mode. Everything is fine as long as the device get lock screen.
When you open the screen and return to the game, it has changed from landscape to portrait mode.

I fixed this with:

1. `stage.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE,Activate);`
2. into `Activate` function: `stage.setAspectRatio(StageAspectRatio.LANDSCAPE);`
3. into `Activate` function: `stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;`

portrait problem is fixed but FULL SCREEN is with android titlebar... How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you confirmed it behaves the same on multiple devices?  You could try waiting a few milliseconds before entering full screen.  Or even better force your app to always be Landscape.   To do that, in your **application.xml** under the `<initialWindow>` node, put this: `<aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>`

Comment: thanks LDMS...but i do that, in my application.xml i hava <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>...My only problem is when the device is locked and then open the screen and return to the game

Comment: OK,my problem solved. i already used ADOBE AIR 3.2 for android device...now i update to ADOBE AIR 3.6, and now everything is Fine.seems that was a BUG from ADOBE AIR,because before the release of a new version of Adobe (CC) there are plugins for this problem on the Internet.

Comment: how to set <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio> in xml it gives error